# How to pass a parameter to a function called as another function's parameter?

Tags: javascript

Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have a function which controls scroll linked animations. I want to call it inside `requestAnimationFrame()`, but I want to pass the `window.pageYOffset` as the function's parameter. Now the code looks like this:

```js
let wH = window.offsetHeight;
let ticking = false
function effects(wT, wH){
//animations using wT, wH
};

window.onresize = () => {
    if (!ticking) {
        wH = window.offsetHeight;
        const wT = window.pageYOffset;
        //I want to pass the wT, and wH to the rAF's parameter,
        //which is the function above. How?
        requestAnimationFrame(effects);
        ticking = true;
    }
}
window.onscroll = () => {
    const wT = window.pageYOffset;
    if (!ticking) {
        //I want to pass the wT, and wH to the rAF's parameter,
        //which is the function above. How?
        requestAnimationFrame(effects);
        ticking = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap that function call inside an anonymous function like so:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    effects(wT, wH);
});
```

Shorter using an arrow function:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => effects(wT, wH));
```